# Flutter Firebase Assign Number

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firebase with flutter. When I try to upload a product I'm getting an error:

```
type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'int'
```

When I typing cost manually in CloudFirestore fixes the problem but I can't add product from my app.

Here's number part of my Product Model:

```
   dynamic newPrice, buyPrice;
      dynamic get getNewPrice=> int.parse(newPrice);
    
      set setNewPrice(dynamic newPrice) =>
          this.newPrice= int.parse(newPrice);
 dynamic get getbuyPrice=> int.parse(buyPrice);

  set setBuyoutPrice(dynamic buyPrice) =>
      this.buyoutPrice = int.parse(buyPrice);
```

**ERROR**

[image]

Comment: Then try parsing the newPrice and buyPrice in double.

Comment: You really should avoid defining variables as dynamic in Dart except for very specific situations. You need to know what type you expect the variable to be.

Comment: i tried parsing double & int really can't figure it out always same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase stores numbers in the double format even if you just send an int, so if you fetch data from firebase of type number you need parse as double. If you type in manually an integer in the firebase console you will be able to parse it like an int but it's just a "manual hack".